# Dropdown based on previous selection is not populating at all

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, drop-down-menu

I am trying to fill in a dropdown list from a mysql table based on the selection on a previous dropdown.

I have looked at many questions asking how to do this and came up wit the follwing,  however nothing is happening to my second dropdown when I select something from the first.

I have newStock.php with the following script in the head.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
<script type="text/javascript">
                $(function(){                    
            $('#field').change(function(){ //on change event
            var fieldVal = $('#field').val(); //<----- get the value from the parent select
            $.ajax({
                url     : 'process.php', //the url you are sending datas to which will again send the result
                type    : 'GET', //type of request, GET or POST
                data    : { fieldValue: fieldVal}, //Data you are sending
                success : function(data){$('#field2').html(data)}, // On success, it will populate the 2nd select
                error   : function(){alert('an error has occured')} //error message
            })
        })

        })
</script>
```

With the two drop downs created in the body:

```
<?php
 connect('final');//connect to DB
 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stockcata");
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
             echo '<option value='.$row['id'].'>' .$row['Catagory']. '</option>';
      }
 ?>
 </Select>  </label> 

 <input type="text" name="addCatagory" />

 <label><span>Section</span> 
 <Select name="field2" id="field2">

 </Select>  </label>
```

And the following process.php used to query my database and provide the options to fill in the second drop down

```
<?php
require("header.php");
connect('final');

$temp = $_GET['fieldValue'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stocksection WHERE cataID = '$temp'");
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 echo '<option value='.$row['id'].'>' .$row['section']. '</option>';
 }
 ?>
```

Nothing happens in the second dropdown, I have no idea why.

Edit.........

I tried to debug it further. My database is set up with 2 tables;
Section: ID, title, Catagory_ID

and Catagory: ID, Title

When it queries the section table it is only returning data with a Catagory_ID of 0, no matter what option I chose from the drop down

Comment: Add debugging lines... Is `data` what you expect? Is it being called? We can not help you out without details.

Comment: Using a debugger, can you tell if the `ajax()` call is ever made? If it returns a value? If that value is properly formed?

Comment: Depending on what's in your `header.php`, JQuery might not be able to correctly infer the type of the server response. It would be safer to just specify `contentType: "text"` in the `ajax()` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data` in the success of your ajax call is not the string you think it is. You probably want something like this:

```
success : function(data){$('#field2').html(data.d)}, // On success,
```

Try a `console.log(data.d);` if that doesn't work to see what you are returning.

Comment: I'm not sure if I am doing this right, I put console.log below 'error :' an get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . " when the page loads

Comment: do it like this: `success : function(data){console.log(data.d);},` and have your console window open to see what it logs.

Comment: Thanks, first time using Javascript and I didn't realise I could debug it like this. It turns out the variable being passed to the fieldVal was wrong causing nothing to be queried correctly.